# How to get the tripoint of three or more polygons in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis

Assume that I have a column containing polygons. What is the SQL statement to get the list of points that three or more polygons touch with each other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get you a point where three geometries touch:

```
WITH polygons AS(
SELECT 1 as id,ST_MakePolygon(ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(0 0,0 2,1 2,1 0,0 0)')) as geom
UNION ALL
SELECT 2,ST_MakePolygon(ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(1 1,2 1,2 2,1 2,1 1)'))
UNION ALL
SELECT 3,ST_MakePolygon(ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(1 0,2 0,2 1,1 1,1 0)'))
)
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT ST_INTERSECTION(ST_INTERSECTION(p1.geom,p2.geom),p3.geom) AS inter
FROM 
    polygons AS p1
    JOIN polygons AS p2
        ON ST_TOUCHES(p1.geom,p2.geom) AND p1.id < p2.id
    JOIN polygons AS p3
        ON ST_TOUCHES(p1.geom,p3.geom) AND ST_TOUCHES(p2.geom,p3.geom) AND p2.id < p3.id;
        ) AS q
WHERE ST_IsEmpty(inter) = false;
```

With a rCTE you could get points where n geometries touch.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it right, you are you looking for the vertex in common of three or more polygons. So you can try this query

```
DROP TABLE points_table_name CASCADE;
CREATE TABLE points_table_name AS
SELECT n_points, geom
FROM
(
  SELECT count(geom) AS n_points, geom
  FROM
  (
    SELECT gid, (ST_DumpPoints(geom)).*
    FROM polygon_table_name
   ) AS foo
  WHERE path<>'{1,1}'
  GROUP BY geom
  ) AS foo1
WHERE n_points>2;
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. It does not solve all the case. Such as tripoint at the star position of these polygons.

http://imgur.com/6weN9dz

Comment: Can you explain better why it does not solve all the case? Maybe I can fix the problem

Comment: For the red polygon, the point that touches the tripoint is not the vertex. ST_DumpPoints is not able to return that point. Am I correct?

Comment: OK now I understand, its not a problem of the query. If a polygon touches another polygon but they don't have vertex in common, the layer is not topologically correct and nothing can give you what you are looking for. You must correct the layer (importing it in grass with a good snap threshold could be enough) and re-execute the query.